# error "Scale for 'fill' is already present" ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble with filling my bar plots, I keep getting the error

> "Scale for 'fill' is already present. Adding another scale for 'fill', which will replace the existing scale."

I would also like the order of the bars to be Control, Predator, Chemical

```
data <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/saraherm/Fear_in_butterflies/master/FC2_alldates_noweather_12.14.16.csv")
data$Treatment<-as.factor(data$Treatment)


my_sum <- data %>%
  group_by(Treatment) %>%
  summarise( 
    n=n(),
    mean=mean(Aphids),
    sd=sd(Aphids)
  ) %>%
  mutate( se=sd/sqrt(n))  %>%
  mutate( ic=se * qt((1-0.05)/2 + .5, n-1))

plot <- ggplot(my_sum) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                      panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))+
  geom_bar( aes(x=Treatment, y=mean), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) +
  geom_errorbar( aes(x=Treatment, ymin=mean-se, ymax=mean+se), width=0.4, colour="black", alpha=0.9, size=1)+
  labs(x="Treatment",y="Average Aphids Per Plant",title="The effect of predator presence on aphid colonization")+
  scale_fill_manual(name="Treatment",values=c("Control"="#56B4E9","Predator"="#0072B2"))+
  scale_color_manual(name="Treatment",values=c("Control"="black","Predator"="black"))+
  theme(text=element_text(family="Avenir",size=14),legend.position="none",axis.title=element_text(size=14),plot.title=element_text(size=16))

plot + paletteer::scale_fill_paletteer_d("wesanderson::Moonrise2")
```

Comment: This is not an error just a message which informs you that you already added a `fill` scale via `scale_fill_manual` which will be replaced when you do `+ paletteer::scale_fill_paletteer_d("wesanderson::Moonrise2")`.

Comment: .. to fix your issue with the order you could do `+ scale_x_discrete(limits = c("Control", "Predator", "Chemical"))` or use `data$Treatment<-factor(data$Treatment, levels = c("Control", "Predator", "Chemical"))` to set the levels of your factor in your desired order.

Comment: The problem is, even if its not a error, I do not get the correct colors in the output, do you if you run it?

Comment: The scales have no effect as you did not map on aesthetics, i.e. try `geom_bar( aes(x=Treatment, y=mean, fill = Treatment), stat="identity", alpha=0.5)` to fill your bars based on Treatment.